# How to combine tables based on timestamps

Tags: sql, vertica

Imagine you have two tables of events.  Both tables A and B have a single column, called timestamp, with multiple rows.

Now I'd like to combine these two tables into a table C with the following properties:

- C has a row for every row in A
- C has a timestamp column that perfectly reflects the contents of A
- C has another column called near_event that is true if there is a row in B within 1s of the timestamp of this row, false otherwise

How might I do that efficiently?

Comment: How close are the timestamps in A?  Are there lots of duplicates?  Is there always more than 1 second between A timestamps?

Comment: There is not always 1s between A events.  There are not any duplicates though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mauro pointed me to this one, saying that Vertica could do better than that - and, indeed, it can, as it has a predicate that enables what we call the *event series join*. All you need to do is to run a non-inner join (left, right or full outer) and use `INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE` intelligently as the join predicate.

You might want to have a look on my LinkedIn post :

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/verticas-event-series-join-joining-two-time-tables-marco-gessner/

.. which illustrates even a more complex use case.

Using the same tables as in that blog:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE oilpressure (
 op_ts,op_psi
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-04-01 07:00:00', 25.356
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-04-01 07:00:10', 35.124
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-04-01 07:00:20', 47.056
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-04-01 07:00:30', 45.225
)
;

CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE revspeed (
 rs_ts,rpm
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-04-01 07:00:00', 2201
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-04-01 07:00:08', 3508
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-04-01 07:00:15', 6504
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-04-01 07:00:20', 6608
)
;
```

Let `oilpressure`be your table A, and `revspeed` be your table B.

Then what you would want (if you only want the timestamps) is this:

```
SELECT
  op_ts
, rs_ts
FROM oilpressure
LEFT JOIN revspeed
ON op_ts INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE rs_ts;
op_ts              |rs_ts
2015-04-01 07:00:00|2015-04-01 07:00:00
2015-04-01 07:00:10|2015-04-01 07:00:08
2015-04-01 07:00:20|2015-04-01 07:00:20
2015-04-01 07:00:30|2015-04-01 07:00:20
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this, if you don't have too many duplicates.  Here is the idea:

```
select timestamp,
       (case when timestamp < timestamp_add(second, 1, last_b_timestamp) or
                  timestamp > timestamp_add(second, -1, next_b_timestamp)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from (select timestamp, which,
             last_value(case when which = 'b' then timestamp) over (order by timestamp) as last_b_timestamp,
             last_value(case when which = 'b' then timestamp) over (order by timestamp desc) as next_b_timestamp,
      from ((select a.timestamp, 'a' as which from a) union all
            (select b.timestamp, 'b' as which from b)
           ) ab
     ) ab
where which = 'a';
```